# reactjs onclick inside map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array that renders a button and when I click this button I need to only change the item of this array connected to that button, adding the name of the user connected to that localStorage. Currently, when I click the button it is changing all the items in the array. To help, I gave a functional example of what I need at this link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/lots-tojln
I need the buttons to work separately

```js
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";
const separator = "/";
export default class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggleButton: true,
      lots: [
        {
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "U",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10
        },
        {
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "M",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10
        }
      ],
      userName: ""
    };
    this.ticketsCheckDocument = this.ticketsCheckDocument.bind(this);
    this.ticketChange = this.ticketChange.bind(this);
  }

  ticketsCheckDocument(e) {
    const [ticketUniqueNumber, lotType, Name] = e.target.value.split(separator);
    console.log(ticketUniqueNumber);
    console.log(lotType);
    console.log(Name);
    this.setState({ toggleButton: false });
    this.setState({ userName: Name });
  }

  ticketChange() {
    this.setState({ toggleButton: true });
    this.setState({ userName: "" });
  }

  render() {
    const lots = this.state.lots.map((lot, l) => (
      <div className="box-ticket" key={l}>
        <div className="box-vertical">
          <h4 className="ticket-type">
            {lot.lotType === "U"
              ? "Unissex"
              : lot.lotType === "M"
              ? "Male"
              : "Female"}{" "}
            <br />
            <small>R$ {lot.lotPrice}</small>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div className="box-text">
          <h4 className="ticket-user-name">{this.state.userName}</h4>
          <p className="text-center">
            The invitations are nominal. <br />
            Please indicate below who will use this invitation
          </p>
          <div className="box-button">
            {this.state.toggleButton ? (
              <div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  value={`${lot.ticketUniqueNumber}${separator}${
                    lot.lotType
                  }${separator}Teste ${l}`}
                  onClick={this.ticketsCheckDocument}
                >
                  It's My
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                  I'll Give
                </button>
              </div>
            ) : (
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={this.ticketChange}
              >
                Change
              </button>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ));
    return <div>{lots}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would move the code to a component and let each component manage it's state.

Comment: But this Card.js its a component

Comment: The sandbox is acting weird for me, could you try my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the whole code a component and let each component manage it's state.

```
class Invitation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toggleButton: true,
    userName: '',
  }

  ticketsCheckDocument = (e) => {
    const [ticketUniqueNumber, lotType, Name] = e.target.value.split(separator);
    console.log(ticketUniqueNumber);
    console.log(lotType);
    console.log(Name);
    this.setState({ toggleButton: false });
    this.setState({ userName: Name });
  }

  ticketChange = () => {
    this.setState({ toggleButton: true });
    this.setState({ userName: "" });
  }

  render() {

    const { lot, index } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="box-ticket">
        <div className="box-vertical">
          <h4 className="ticket-type">
            {lot.lotType === "U"
              ? "Unissex"
              : lot.lotType === "M"
                ? "Male"
                : "Female"}{" "}
            <br />
            <small>R$ {lot.lotPrice}</small>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div className="box-text">
          <h4 className="ticket-user-name">{this.state.userName}</h4>
          <p className="text-center">
            The invitations are nominal. <br />
            Please indicate below who will use this invitation
          </p>
          <div className="box-button">
            {this.state.toggleButton ? (
              <div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  value={`${lot.ticketUniqueNumber}${separator}${lot.lotType
                    }${separator}Teste ${index}`}
                  onClick={this.ticketsCheckDocument}
                >
                  It's My
                </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                  I'll Give
                </button>
              </div>
            ) : (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.ticketChange}
                >
                  Change
              </button>
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<style>
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.box-ticket {
  background-image: url(./images/ticket03.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 140px;
  background-position-x: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.box-vertical {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  width: 160px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  top: 50px;
  left: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.box-vertical h3 {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.box-vertical h4 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.box-vertical .ticket-type small {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box-ticket .box-text {
  height: 140px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff !important;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.box-ticket .box-text p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.box-text .box-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box-text .box-button button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(230, 45, 85, 0.85);
  border-color: transparent;
}
.box-text form > button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(230, 45, 85, 0.85);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.box-text .box-button .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active {
  background-color: rgba(230, 45, 85, 1);
  border-color: transparent;
}

.box-text .box-button .btn:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.ticket-user-name {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  min-height: auto;
  height: 15px;
  left: -10px;
  position: relative;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.installments-warning {
  color: #737373;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.total-interest {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #737373;
}

</style>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Invitation extends React.Component {
  state = {
    toggleButton: true,
    userName: '',
  }

  ticketsCheckDocument = (e) => {
    const [ticketUniqueNumber, lotType, Name] = e.target.value.split(separator);
    console.log(ticketUniqueNumber);
    console.log(lotType);
    console.log(Name);
    this.setState({ toggleButton: false });
    this.setState({ userName: Name });
  }

  ticketChange = () => {
    this.setState({ toggleButton: true });
    this.setState({ userName: "" });
  }

  render() {

    const { lot, index } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="box-ticket">
        <div className="box-vertical">
          <h4 className="ticket-type">
            {lot.lotType === "U"
              ? "Unissex"
              : lot.lotType === "M"
                ? "Male"
                : "Female"}{" "}
            <br />
            <small>R$ {lot.lotPrice}</small>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div className="box-text">
          <h4 className="ticket-user-name">{this.state.userName}</h4>
          <p className="text-center">
            The invitations are nominal. <br />
            Please indicate below who will use this invitation
              </p>
          <div className="box-button">
            {this.state.toggleButton ? (
              <div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  value={`${lot.ticketUniqueNumber}${separator}${lot.lotType
                    }${separator}Teste ${index}`}
                  onClick={this.ticketsCheckDocument}
                >
                  It's My
                    </button>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">
                  I'll Give
                    </button>
              </div>
            ) : (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={this.ticketChange}
                >
                  Change
                  </button>
              )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


const separator = "/";
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toggleButton: true,
      lots: [
        {
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "U",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10
        },
        {
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "M",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10
        }
      ],
      userName: ""
    };
    this.ticketsCheckDocument = this.ticketsCheckDocument.bind(this);
    this.ticketChange = this.ticketChange.bind(this);
  }

  ticketsCheckDocument(e) {
    const [ticketUniqueNumber, lotType, Name] = e.target.value.split(separator);
    console.log(ticketUniqueNumber);
    console.log(lotType);
    console.log(Name);
    this.setState({ toggleButton: false });
    this.setState({ userName: Name });
  }

  ticketChange() {
    this.setState({ toggleButton: true });
    this.setState({ userName: "" });
  }

  render() {
    const lots = this.state.lots.map((lot, l) => (<Invitation index={l} lot={lot} key={l} />));
    return <div>{lots}</div>;
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Card />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: This solve my problem, thanks. I put the code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/lots-tojln

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `userName` and `toggleButton` properties of each object in `lots`. Then you can pass the index of the lot to the `ticketsCheckDocument` to update the corresponding lot element.

Try this:

```js
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";
const separator = "/";
export default class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

      lots: [{
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "U",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10,
          toggleButton: true,
          userName: ""
        },
        {
          lotNumber: "1",
          lotPrice: "10.00",
          lotPriceTax: "0.00",
          lotType: "M",
          lotUniqueNumber: "xZ38Dw7bDwD33z469xcB4yy3b64D3z",
          quantity: 2,
          ticketName: "Camarote",
          ticketPrevenda: "false",
          ticketUniqueNumber: "3WaDBCcawdzyZdAZYBCBz1zb170x47",
          total: 20,
          totalLotPrice: 10,
          toggleButton: true,
          userName: ""
        }
      ],

    };
    this.ticketsCheckDocument = this.ticketsCheckDocument.bind(this);
    this.ticketChange = this.ticketChange.bind(this);
  }

  ticketsCheckDocument(e, i) {
    const [ticketUniqueNumber, lotType, Name] = e.target.value.split(separator);
    console.log(ticketUniqueNumber);
    console.log(lotType);
    console.log(Name);
    const lots = [...this.state.lots];
    lots[i].toggleButton = false;
    lots[i].userName = Name;
    this.setState({
      lots
    })
  }

  ticketChange() {
    this.setState({
      toggleButton: true
    });
    this.setState({
      userName: ""
    });
  }

  render() {
    const lots = this.state.lots.map((lot, l) => ( <
      div className = "box-ticket"
      key = {
        l
      } >
      <
      div className = "box-vertical" >
      <
      h4 className = "ticket-type" > {
        lot.lotType === "U" ?
        "Unissex" :
          lot.lotType === "M" ?
          "Male" :
          "Female"
      } {
        " "
      } <
      br / >
      <
      small > R$ {
        lot.lotPrice
      } < /small> <
      /h4> <
      /div> <
      div className = "box-text" >
      <
      h4 className = "ticket-user-name" > {
        this.state.userName
      } < /h4> <
      p className = "text-center" >
      The invitations are nominal. < br / >
      Please indicate below who will use this invitation <
      /p> <
      div className = "box-button" > {
        lot.toggleButton ? ( <
          div >
          <
          button type = "button"
          className = "btn btn-primary"
          value = {
            `${lot.ticketUniqueNumber}${separator}${
                    lot.lotType
                  }${separator}Teste ${l}`
          }
          onClick = {
            e => this.ticketsCheckDocument(e, i)
          } >
          It 's My <
          /button> <
          button type = "button"
          className = "btn btn-primary" >
          I 'll Give <
          /button> <
          /div>
        ) : ( <
          button type = "button"
          className = "btn btn-primary"
          onClick = {
            this.ticketChange
          } >
          Change <
          /button>
        )
      } <
      /div> <
      /div> <
      /div>
    ));
    return <div > {
      lots
    } < /div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to make it work, seems to break when you click the button.

Comment: @JuniusL. I'm not sure it'll work in here. Please try replacing the component in your sandbox with my original code.

Comment: I removed my changes.

Comment: Almost: https://codesandbox.io/embed/lots-tojln I can not show the name on the ticket